# Best lighting for minimal shadows for product-on-white rendering

Tags: light, workflow, lighting, shadows

I produce a lot of basic "product on white" renderings for Amazon images. I have a few methods for getting to what I want, but most involve quite a bit of rendering multiple images and compositing via Photoshop, etc. I'm wondering if anyone can offer advice on their preferred workflow to get the best on white product images straight out of one render without having to edit. A couple things I'm looking for advice on acheiving:

1. Pure white background (do you use a seamless and light it? or
   just use a white background? Any other tricks?)
2. Minimal shadows - on Amazon, the container is a tightly cropped
   square, so dealing with shadows is an issue and you can't rely on
   those nice long, realistic shadows - I'm trying to determine how to
   get minimal shadows like the attached examples straight out of the
   gate with no editing. I realize the answer lies in lighting, but it
   seems that if I adjust the lighting to make the least amount of
   shadow, my subject's lighting suffers, and vise versa. Have you
   found any ways to control the shadows separately from the lighting
   of the object?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Pure white background is easy to achieve. Don't put any kind of floor under the product, in the _Render Properties_ panel set _Film > Transparent_ and in the Compositor you mix the rendered image with the _Alpha Over Node_ over white colour. For the separate shadow I have to test something tomorrow, but I think there's a way, too.

Comment: Oh, of course if you want some floor reflecting light or anything on the product without being visible, select the floor, go to the _Visibility_ settings and disable _Camera_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve the desired result it's best to create two scenes: the first one for the product, the second for the shadow.

1. The first scene contains the product and all lighting like lamps, HDRI environment etc. for lighting the product as it should look like. A floor maybe for light bounces or blocking light from below the product. Set *Render Properties > Film > Transparent*. Hide the floor from the camera by disabling *Object Properties > Visibility > Ray Visibility > Camera*.
2. Create the second scene by copying the first one (a word on linked duplicates at the end of this answer). Make the floor visible again by enabling *Ray Visibility > Camera* and enable *Visibility > Ray Visibility > Shadow Catcher*. Delete all lamps, set *World > Strength* to 0.0, put a plane with Emission shader above the product and play with the settings until the shadow is correct. Now hide the product from the camera like you did with the floor in the other scene.

[image: Scene setup]

3. Now both scenes are setup for rendering. In the *Compositor*, choose a *Render Layer Node*  for the shadow scene and use an *Alpha Over Node* with a white colour to put the shadow on a white background. Add a second *Render Layer Node* for the product scene and place it above the shadowed background with another *Alpha Over Node*.

[image: Compositing]

4. If you hit <kbd>F12</kbd> now to render the image, both scenes will be rendered and composited together.

You can now maybe save the setup as a stage for other products. If you want to change something on the product or the floor without having to create the shadow scene again it's best to make those objects linked duplicates, so any changes will apply to both of them. It's important that they're not the same objects just linked to both scenes, otherwise they cannot have different viisibility settings.

A last side note on rendering with *Color Management* set to *Filmic*: because it has a much higher dynamic range, the 'normal' white with a brightness of 1 will usually be a light grey instead of pure white. To achieve pure white in *Filmic* the background white must have a brightness of around 16.19 - which means, the shadow seems to disappear. Considering you want to render with *Filmic* it would be the best only composite the shadow and product over a transparent background and add the white in another program like Photoshop, Gimp etc.

//Edit: I've uploaded a file where I show the things described in the comments.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Gordon, really appreciate your detailed response -- one thing I'm a little confused on is the Emission shader plane - can you show me the setup for nodes for this? I have it in place but can't seem to figure out how to adjust the size/diffusion of the shadow??

Comment: I'm also having trouble outputting the composite with a transparent background - can you clarify how I would do that in the node setup? As you say, the white background is not ideal for this but can't seem to figure it out with this setup - thanks again!

Comment: To output it on a transparent background you just plug the _Render Layers_ node of the shadow scene directly into the first socket of the _Alpha Over_ node and the product scene into the second socket, so you simply don't put it over white color at the beginning. Then save it as a PNG ot TIF set to RGBA.

Comment: For the shadow, here's a few tricks: since this scene only shows a shadow on the floor,, no object, no light etc., you can manipulate it in some ways. For example, if the shadow gets too large in diameter, try adjusting the size and height of the emission plane above it. Or even the strength. If your shadow gets to sharp, maybe blur it in the _Compositor_ before the _Alpha Over_. The width of shadows not only depends on the relation of the light plane's size and height above object, but also the height of the object itself. Try putting the bottom half of the product on the floor for example.

Comment: Cutting off the top the product can also be done non-destrucive by using a _Boolean Modifier_. I'll take a cube, set it to _Intersect_ and choose the product in the _Object_ selection. I'll edit my answer and attach a file where I do all those tricks.